# How make a perl script quit or end when the client connection to xinetd terminates?

Tags: perl, xinetd

I have a perl script which uses blocking IO (sysread and syswrite).

This script is connected to a xinetd server listening on a TCP port.
I Heard that xinetd puts a SIGHUP when client disconnects, so I tried with:

```
$SIG{HUP} = sub { die; };
```

but didnt work, theres a lot of lingering processes when running ps -A.

Any ideas?

Comment: SIGHUP's default action is to kill the process, so you wouldn't have to set a signal handler. Do you otherwise play with signals?

Comment: I can't find anything about xinetd sending a SIGHUP when a client disconnects, and I don't know of any mechanism by which it could do that without reading from the client, and that would steal the data from the process which is suppose to be reading from the client. You should probably be using IO::Select instead of blocking IO, and you should include the client socket in the select. (If the select says data is available on the client socket and a sysread returns 0, the connection was closed.)

Comment: The process is not killed when client disconnects or timeouts. Can this be a problem in xinetd config? What do you mean with including the client socket? xinetd pipes data to STDIN and reads from STDOUT, so you do not get access to the raw socket.